# Django CSRF failing with .env file for Docker

Tags: python, django, docker, csrf

Hi I'm using Docker to build a Django web application via Docker-Compose and it uses the .env.dev file for the environmental variables.

The problem is the CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS variables :

- If i put variables inside the settings.py  => Ok
- If i put variables inside the env.dev => KO (  `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'`)

settings.py

```
# CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS=["https://www.site1.fr", "http://www.site1.fr"]
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS= os.environ.get("DJANGO_CSRF").split(" ")
```

env.dev

```
DJANGO_CSRF=https://www.site1.fr http://www.site1.fr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to name you file `dev.env` or just `.env`.

After renaming your file, remember to use `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up` so the environment variables get updated with the container